# How to turn my android app into default sms application?

Tags: sms, android-sms

I am working on an android  project within it  i have implemented a sms module where i can send sms and receive sms . But i want my app to be used as the default sms app which means that received sms must not be seen in the sms app . How could i figure this out ?